# Angular 1.5 ng-repeat and custom filter on scope model update (through the filter itself) not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using 2 `ng-repeats` to construct a table which is in fact sitting inside a *ui-bootstrap accordion*, itself created using `ng-repeat`.

Also, I am using a filter on the `ng-repeat` which essentially returns only 12 elements out of 36.

The input to the filter is a pagination handler variable which stores the current page.

*E.g.*

If the current page is 1, return elements 1-12

Else if it's 2, return elements 13-24,

else 25-36

Each `<td>` is editable & I have written a directive for it to update the model from the ui.

The problem is:

The filter works fine if I remove `contenteditable="true"` from `<td>`. But doesn't work when I use it.

What could be reason ?

<strike>P.S. : I will be adding the code soon</strike>

*Update* https://jsfiddle.net/f5uzjcqc/6/

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Comment: I have added the code. Pls have a look if you can

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the evaluated code passed into ng-model. You are indexing your array using $index but that will always be 0-12 (i.e. the length of the filtered array) and do not correlate to the full indices of your array.

You will likely need to use your variable assigned in ng-repeat (baselineDatum) or find another way to get the actual array index.